# WhatsApp: incremental backup possible?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I share my phone at home and I know sometimes some of my WhatsApp messages are deleted from my chat history. Sometimes I end up dieting some videos from WhatsApp myself due to lack of space on the device. I would like to know whether it is possible to perform an incremental backup to Google Drive, so that I can restore a video or part of a chat from any date in case I decide to delete it locally and the standard WhatsApp backup to Google Drive deletes this part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp backup on Google Drive is *incremental* as you can read in [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000019/?category=5245251)

But you can't *restore a video or part of a chat from any date in case I decide to delete it locally.....*,that's not possible and you would need to restore in full not selectively by date or content

Comment: Can I at least peek at the incremental backup using Google Drive or other means to retrieve a part of a deleted conversation?

Comment: Where in the link you provided does it say the backup is incremental as in keeping snapshots of previous backups, adding the delta's like source control does (like CVS current versioning system). If it does not then is there a CVS-like app replacement? Thanks.

Comment: @NeilZaneil- AFAIK No and I haven't heard of such utility for users (not talking of database admins)

Comment: under creating Google Drive Backup -*However, subsequent backups are **incremental**, thus not requiring a completely new backup of all your data every time.* I am not familiar with CVS system , sorry, can't comment on that . But I am very sure that as a user you can't do what you asked in the question

Comment: CVS is one of the older precursors of Git, the source control system by Linus Torvalds that everyone uses nowadays; it uses all of the same ideas, just more prehistoric and slower.